# System log waring makes no sence

Tags: magento-1.9, template, varnish, system.log

I'm getting the below warning error in my Magento *system.log* and I can't figure out what could be causing it.

```
2015-11-06T11:56:19+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: File not found: /var/www/magento-root/app/design/frontend/custom-design-package/default/template  in /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php on line 241
```

It says file not found on a directory rather than a file which is confusing.

I've looked in Mage/Core/Block/Template.php at line 241 (`include $includeFilePath;`) and can't see what could be causing it.

```
    public function fetchView($fileName)
    {
        Varien_Profiler::start($fileName);

        // EXTR_SKIP protects from overriding
        // already defined variables
        extract ($this->_viewVars, EXTR_SKIP);
        $do = $this->getDirectOutput();

        if (!$do) {
            ob_start();
        }
        if ($this->getShowTemplateHints()) {
            echo <<<HTML
<div style="position:relative; border:1px dotted red; margin:6px 2px; padding:18px 2px 2px 2px; zoom:1;">
<div style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; padding:2px 5px; background:red; color:white; font:normal 11px Arial;
text-align:left !important; z-index:998;" onmouseover="this.style.zIndex='999'"
onmouseout="this.style.zIndex='998'" title="{$fileName}">{$fileName}</div>
HTML;
            if (self::$_showTemplateHintsBlocks) {
                $thisClass = get_class($this);
                echo <<<HTML
<div style="position:absolute; right:0; top:0; padding:2px 5px; background:red; color:blue; font:normal 11px Arial;
text-align:left !important; z-index:998;" onmouseover="this.style.zIndex='999'" onmouseout="this.style.zIndex='998'"
title="{$thisClass}">{$thisClass}</div>
HTML;
            }
        }

        try {
            $includeFilePath = realpath($this->_viewDir . DS . $fileName);
            if (strpos($includeFilePath, realpath($this->_viewDir)) === 0 || $this->_getAllowSymlinks()) {
                include $includeFilePath;  // THIS IS LINE 241
            } else {
                Mage::log('Not valid template file:'.$fileName, Zend_Log::CRIT, null, null, true);
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            ob_get_clean();
            throw $e;
        }

        if ($this->getShowTemplateHints()) {
            echo '</div>';
        }

        if (!$do) {
            $html = ob_get_clean();
        } else {
            $html = '';
        }
        Varien_Profiler::stop($fileName);
        return $html;
    }
```

Any ideas, Sorry I don't have more info.

---

## UPDATE

*$this->_viewDir . DS . $fileName* (l. 239) evaluates to

```
/var/www/magento-root/app/design/frontend/my-theme/default/template/manapro/filtertree/item.phtml
ManaPro_FilterTree_Block_Item
```

And the class name of **$this** is `ManaPro_FilterTree_Block_Item` which extends Mage_Core_Block_Template.

Also here is the full stack trace.

```
Warning: include(/var/www/magento-root/app/design/frontend/my-theme/default/template): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php on line 241

#0 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(/var/ww...', '/var/www/houseo...', 241, Array)
#1 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): Mage_Core_Block_Template::fetchView()
#2 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/my-theme/de...')
#3 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/community/Nexcessnet/Turpentine/Block/Product/Compared.php(27): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#4 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Nexcessnet_Turpentine_Block_Product_Compared->_toHtml()
#5 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#7 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#9 /var/www/magento-root/app/design/frontend/blacknwhite/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(50): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#10 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/houseo...')
#11 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/blackn...')
#12 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#16 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#17 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#18 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#19 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 /var/www/magento-root/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 /var/www/magento-root/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#23 {main}
```

*app/code/community/Nexcessnet/Turpentine/Block/Product/Compared.php* seems to be part of the issue.

```
<?php

/**
 * Nexcess.net Turpentine Extension for Magento
 * Copyright (C) 2012  Nexcess.net L.L.C.
 */

class Nexcessnet_Turpentine_Block_Product_Compared extends Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Compared {

    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (!$this->getCount()) {
            return $this->renderView();
        }

        $this->setRecentlyComparedProducts($this->getItemsCollection());

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

In particular `return $this->renderView();` evaluates to just an empty string, `""`.  And when I disable the `Nexcessnet_Turpentine` the warning goes away.

Answer (score 1):

The `$includeFilePath` is a calculated/modified value and not directly the source of your trouble. In order to track that down, you need to

1. find out what `$this->_viewDir . DS . $fileName` (l. 239) evaluates to and
2. what block type (class name of `$this`, descendant of `Mage_Core_Block_Template`) is affected when the error occurs.

I am pretty sure that an invalid template file is set to a block.

Comment: @mam08xio, what exactly do you mean by *an invalid template file is set to a block*? Do you mean that a template has been assigned to the wrong block type?  Thanks for the tips, It's only occuring on our production enviroment so I'll try out your suggestions with a fresh DB dump soon.

Comment: By _invalid template file_ I mean a file that does not exist in the file system. The file name is determined by the concatenation given above. If template files are symlinked, make sure the system configuration setting `dev/template/allow_symlink` is correct.

Comment: @marn08ixo I have Allow Symlinks set to No as it is a production enviroment

Comment: That is fine as long as your template files are not symlinked :)

Comment: I finally got around to debugging this locally, still can't figure it out.   I've updated my answer with more details, if you have time to look over it?  Thanks